# How can I have proper borders around the middle element?

Tags: css

How can I have proper borders around the midItem element?

http://jsfiddle.net/PmfLm/

Here is the minified code of the same fiddle,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    span,.midItem {
        border-style: solid;
    }
    .midItem {
        border-color: blue;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    p {
        text-align:justify;     
    }
    .leftPage,.rightPage{
        display:inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .centerBox {
        display:table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .leftBox,.rightBox {
        display: table;
        border-style:dotted; 
        border-width:5px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-color:green;
    }
    .leftBox,.leftPage {
        float:left; 
    }
    .rightBox,.rightPage {
        float:right; 
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="leftPage"><span class="leftBox"><p class="centerBox">Leftbox</p></span>
<p>Some Text</p>
</span>
<span class="rightPage"><span class="rightBox"><p class="centerBox">rightBox</p></span>
<p>SomeText</p>
</span>
<p class="midItem">SomeText</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not getting your question properly but do you need something like this? If yes than clear your floats, use `overflow: hidden;` for the container div

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PmfLm/2/)

CSS

```
span,.midItem {
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I will mark this as an answer in short time. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: How can I remove the floats and still get the same result?

Comment: Read this article on floats, http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/, you can also use `clear: both;` to clear your floats ;)

Comment: Ok. Understood now ( After reading that article + some thinking ). I am core C++ programmer. Finding CSS complicated, I believe drawing the webapp with Canvas through code will be simpler. :)

Comment: For Canvas you should know javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use table-cell to get the same height in all elements, then you should set it to all three elements

```
.midItem {
    border-color: blue;
    padding: 5px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.leftBox,.leftPage {
    display:table-cell;
}
.rightBox,.rightPage {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PmfLm/3/